# What are the current statistics of migrations to other sites?

Tags: discussion, statistics, migration

Are the current statistics of questions migrated to other sites visible somewhere? I suspect it is available through https://math.stackexchange.com/tools/posts/migrated/stats for > 10k rep users, so I can't see it at the moment. Perhaps someone can publish it?

Specifically, I am interested in how many questions were migrated to stats.stackexchange.com and physics.stackexchange.com versus number of questions migrated to stackoverflow.com (for example during last few years or so), just to see if there is or is not a basis for allowing to flag for migration to the later site as well.

Migration statistics to other sites could be also interesting if they are comparable to the above sites.

Comment: I was thinking about posting a question here on the same topic after I found a question in the review queue that should have gone to stackoverflow (essentially how do I implement X in the statistic program R). After recommending migration I also expected the option to just choose any SE site as target. Even it is not common, the situations do arise.

Comment: Curious, why would someone want to know the migration statistics?

Comment: @FuzzySquid I say it in the question itself. Basically choice of sites that can be selected for migration is based on statistics, so if statistics tell that there is overwhelming number of migrations to stack overflow, it should indeed be added to the list.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Overall there are very few migrations.

Over the last 90 days there were only 8 migrations to Cross Validated (the statistics site) and also 8 to Physics (one of them rejected). Moreover there were 2 to our own meta site.

As regards incoming migrations there were about 30 from each of MathOverflow and Physics, and about 10 from each of Cross Validated and Mathematica. 
In addition there are about ten sites from which a single question was migrated.

There might be somewhat more migrations to other sites if moderators would migrate more based on flags raised with this request. However, in many cases I do not believe in the usefulness of migration. It is usually better for everyone involved to just post to the other site (deleting the original or with bidirectional links).

Comment: yeah part of the annoyance is every topic has overlaps with most of the rest.

Answer (score 16):

[image]