# Why can't Math StackExchange questions be flagged as belonging in a site other than math meta, stats, or physics?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, flagging, migration

I have noticed a few questions that don't belong on math StackExchange, math meta, stats StackExchange, or physics StackExchange. I cannot flag them as belonging in another site, so I just post a comment. Can someone add the option to flag as belonging in a site in StackExchange other than the three listed? If I really feel it belongs in another site, is posting a comment the right way to get the moderator's attention?

Comment: Did you search for previous questions about this? I suck at searching stackexchange, but I would find it hard to believe this hasn't already been discussed.

Comment: In the [tag-info for migration](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/tags/migration/info), you can find links to FAQ posts on [meta.se].
You can look at some older discusisons on this meta, too - such as:
[This question belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/12960),
[Why can't I select any other SE website when flagging a question?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/32166) or 
[Flagging for migration to Mathematica.SE and Computational Science.SE](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3853).

Comment: After MO joined the network, there was a discussion whether it should be included, too: [What, when and will we migrate questions to MO 2.0?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4880) 
Some stats can be found here: [What are the current statistics of migrations to other sites?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/30785) - and users with sufficient reputation have [access to current stats(https://math.stackexchange.com/tools?tab=migrated&daterange=today). Of course, if you want to migrate to a different site, you can still flag for moderators' attention.

Comment: math.se is not the gate keeper to all sites.

Comment: What @amWhy said. If there's a problem to be fixed—and I'm not convinced there is—it's a problem for the entire ecosystem, not for Math.SE. Fixing it just for Math.SE doesn't make much sense; it doesn't scale.